# Selfadjointness of hamiltonian with 1/x potential

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let us consider the Hilbert space $L^2([0,\infty))$ and operator $H=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \frac{1}{x}$ on the domain of $C^{\infty}_0((0,\infty))$ (smooth functions with compact support away from $0$).

Is the operator H essentially self-adjoint? What is the domain of its self-adjoint extension?

Comment: The recent edit seemed completely gratuitous, and it is debatable if the changes made any substantive improvement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is classical and negative. It is a particular instance of Thm X.11 of Reed-Simon [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125850026).

Let $V(x)$ be a continous potential on $(0,+\infty)$. If
\begin{equation}
V(x) \geq \frac{3}{4x^2}
\end{equation}
Then $-\partial_x^2 +V$ it is essentially self-adjoint. On the other hand, if for some $\varepsilon >0$
\begin{equation}
0\leq V(x) \leq \left(\frac{3}{4} - \varepsilon\right)\frac{1}{x^2}
\end{equation}
Then $-\partial_x^2 +V$ is not essentially self-adjoint

Comment: The inequality $0\leq V(x) \leq \left(\frac{3}{4} - \varepsilon\right)\frac{1}{x^2}$ does not hold everywhere for $V(x)=1/x$. Is it not a problem?

Comment: No, it is not a problem. If you have that inequality only near 0, then the operator is in the "limit circle" case near 0. By Weyl's  criterion (R&S Theorem X.7), it is not essentially self-adjoint.

Comment: Are there any self-adjoint extensions of the considered operator. E.g. is the operator H self-adjoint on the domain $\{ f\in L^2([0,\infty)): f'' \in  L^2([0,\infty)), f(0)=0\}$?

Comment: Yes, this is one possible self-adjoint extension (with Dirichlet boundary condition). Characterizing all the infinite self-adjoint extension is not really straightforward, but they are listed, e.g., here: http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.2764